# Bean for message channel not found causes flaky integration test

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-integration

We're experiencing flaky integration tests using Spring Integration Flow for e-mail sending.

We're using a `@MessagingGateway` for sending a `MimeMessage` to an integration flow.

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface MimeMessageSender
{
    @Gateway(requestChannel = EMailConfig.OUTBOUND_MAIL_CHANNEL_NAME)
    void send(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MailException;
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class EMailConfig
{
    public static final String MAIL_OUTBOUND_ENDPOINT_ID = "mailOutbound.mailOutboundAdapter";
    public static final String OUTBOUND_MAIL_CHANNEL_NAME = "outboundMailChannel";

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mailOutbound(final MailSender mailSender)
    {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(OUTBOUND_MAIL_CHANNEL_NAME)
                .handle(Mail.outboundAdapter(mailSender), e -> e.id(MAIL_OUTBOUND_ENDPOINT_ID))
                .get();
    }
}
```

Integration tests may fail randomly with this error:

```
ERROR [task-5] org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler: Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void emailmgmt.infrastructure.integration.EmailSender.outboundEmailCreated(emailmgmt.domain.model.outboundemail.event.OutboundEmailCreated)
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'outboundMailChannel' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:872)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:45)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.getRequestChannel(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:386)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:421)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:656)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:588)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:555)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:544)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy280.send(Unknown Source)
    at emailmgmt.infrastructure.integration.EmailSender.doSend(EmailSender.java:76)
    at emailmgmt.infrastructure.integration.EmailSender.outboundEmailCreated(EmailSender.java:57)
    at emailmgmt.infrastructure.integration.EmailSender$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$13a22e71.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

On startup of the application context we see that the "outboundMailChannel" bean exists and the outbound email adapter gets subscribed:

```
INFO  [main] org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor: Adding {mail:outbound-channel-adapter:mailOutbound.mailOutboundAdapter} as a subscriber to the 'outboundMailChannel' channel
INFO  [main] org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor: Channel 'project-name.outboundMailChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
```

If we run the integration test standalone, it succeeds.

If we run the integration test with some other tests, it succeeds too.

If we run all integration tests, some tests using the "outboundMailChannel" fail with the previous error message.

So what could be the cause that the bean is not found?

Comment: `Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void emailmgmt.infrastructure.integration.EmailSender.outboundEmailCreated(emailmgmt.domain.model.outboundemail.event.OutboundEmailCreated)`. What is that async method and why it is initiated too early when the application context is not fully ready yet?

Comment: @ArtemBilan: The `MimeMessageSender` is called in the following hierarchy: An ApplicationEvent is fired in which indicates that an outbound email must be sent. The handler method is annotated with `@TransactionalEventListener @Transactional @Async`. This method fires another ApplicationEvent indicating that the Outbound Email is persisted and needs to be given to the outbound email adapter. This is handled by `EmailSender.outboundEmailCreated(OutboundEmailCreated)` being annotated with `@TransactionalEventListener @Transactional @Async`.

Comment: Ok. How does it work if your remove that `@Async`? Otherwise I'm not sure in a  `@Transactional` when it is `@Async`: the action is going to happen on another thread than you receive that `TransactionEvent`, so starting a new transaction around placing the task into a queue of the executor is not practical at all. I'd like to reproduce the issue and see if we need to fix something on the framework side in regards of the lifecycle, but I guess it is going to be hard for your to share with us something pretty simple and reproducable. I wonder if something like `@DirtiesContext` helps you...

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Thanks for having a look at this issue! I've to mention we're using Spring Boot 2.5.14 currently.
Removing @Async is not an option since it decouples the business logic from e-mail sending and the pattern `@TransactionalEventListener @Transactional @Async` is working fine to achieve this.
You've mentioned `@DirtiesContext`: I've checked the debug logs of the `TestContext` caching. The tests re-use cached application contexts, maybe this is causing some trouble in the Spring Integration components?

Comment: Maybe, so would be great to be able to reproduce in a simple way so we can fix whatever is wrong. Would you mind to explain `@TransactionalEventListener @Transactional @Async` pattern? I understand what is `@TransactionalEventListener` and understand what is `@Async`, but I'm not fully sure how `@Transactional` works with that `@Async`. Do you really see a new transaction on that method call from other thread?

Comment: @ArtemBilan: The mentioned pattern is based on this article: https://dzone.com/articles/transaction-synchronization-and-spring-application. The async method is `@Transactional` since the event contains the id only, and the async method gathers additional data from database by querying further information by the given id.

Comment: Right. But I don't see `@Transactional` on an `@Async` method. It is on the target service method called from that async one... Anyway this is a different story and would be great to see your finding about that missed channel during testing.

Comment: @ArtemBilan: I'll see if I can provide you a sample application. What would be the best way to provide it to you?

Comment: GitHub repository.

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Finally had the time to create an example application, see https://github.com/sbillmaier/flaky-integration-test-email-oubound-example. By invoking `mvnw clean verify` the integration tests are executed. The current workaround is to `@SpyBean` the MimeMessageSender.

Comment: Your project doesn't fail for me. Not sure what we are talking about... See if you also can upgrade to the latest Spring Boot: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Sorry if there was some misunderstanding: Since we cannot reproduce the issue in a stable manner (and cannot provide you the whole codebase neither) this example was meant to show you the basic architecture of the application. Maybe you can see hints for causing the flaky test. We're currently on the way to upgrade to the latest Spring Boot 3 release, too.

Comment: No, everything looks like. But I guess the problem is because you just show here only one test while in your case there are many and probably all of them share the same configuration. So, one of the test might close the `ApplicationContext` for some reason while another one tries to get access to beans which are not there any more. In our tests we use a `@DiritesContext` for all tests classes to have them all in isolation and rely on their own `ApplicationContext` instance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this and has some strange issues like this or "no subscribers" for channels: Using a static reference to `ApplicationEventPublisher` is a *very bad idea!*

That caused the problem described.

Since the `TestContext` is cached, this static reference caused that application events were sent to the wrong `ApplicationContext`.